# One time execution of "do" in a do-while loop

Tags: c

my goal is to make triangles with #. it does not print the code "Height(a number from 1 to 8):" when a value not between 1-8 is entered in the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int h;
    do{
        printf("Height(a number from 1 to 8): ");
        h = get_int("");

    }while((h<1)||(h>8));{
       for(int i=0; i<h;i++){
           for(int j=0; j<=i; j++){
               printf("#");
           }
           printf("\n");
       }
    
    }
}
```

how can I print "Height(a number from 1 to 8):" repeatedly until I enter a number 1-8?

Comment: Think about the logic for a while: How can `h<1` ***and*** `h>8` both be true at the same time?

Comment: Also please think about the formatting of the code. The code following the `do { ... } while(...);` loop is *not* part of the loop. The following code block is kind of misleading.

Comment: What is the function `get_int`? Are you using the CS50 library? Did you forget to `#include <cs50.h>`?

Comment: Additional reminder: If you use the [CS50's get_int](https://manual.cs50.io/3/get_int) library, you can pass the `"Height(a number from 1 to 8): "` string as its parameter instead of printing it  using the `printf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it does not print the code "Height(a number from 1 to 8):" when a value not between 1-8 is entered in the code below

Yes it does, though you might have to "flush" the stdout buffer. This can likely be done by adding a new line character to printf:

`printf("Height(a number from 1 to 8): \n");`

Or in case you are using some exotic system, `fflush(stdout);` will always work.

Also the logic is wrong:
"while h is less than 1 and h is larger than 8, loop" - should be
"while h is less than 1 *OR* h is larger than 8".

---

Also, the sloppy code formatting with braces all over isn't doing you any favors when it comes to understanding your own code. Rewrite it to something readable:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int h;
    do{
        printf("Height(a number from 1 to 8): \n");
        h = get_int("");
    } while( (h<1) || (h>8) );

    for(int i=0; i<h; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<=i; j++){
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```